# TYPO3 tx_news extension not using override template

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I have two sites using the tx_news extension. As far as I can tell they are set up identically. On site A I have added a new List.html partial and it works as expected. On site B however it is completely ignoring my List override.

I have triple checked the file path to make sure the typoscript points to the right place but it still uses the default. What could be wrong here?

```
plugin.tx_news {
  view {
    templateRootPaths >
    templateRootPaths {
      0 = EXT:news/Resources/Private/Templates/
      1 = fileadmin/templates/example/news/Templates/
    }
    partialRootPaths >
    partialRootPaths {
      0 = EXT:news/Resources/Private/Partials/
      1 = fileadmin/templates/example/news/Partials/
    }
    layoutRootPaths >
    layoutRootPaths {
      0 = EXT:news/Resources/Private/Layouts/
      1 = fileadmin/templates/example/news/Layouts/
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check in the BE in the TypoScript Object Browser if you see this lines by the Setup of your template.

Comment: @AndrásOttó Checking the Object Browser showed I had a } missing earlier in the setup script. Adding it back in fixed the problem. Simple! Make an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script looks good. When something like this happens in TYPO3 there is an option to check whatever your TypoScript valid or this changes are really added into the right place.

Go into the BE, select the **Template** module and with the **TypoScript Object Browser** you can see if in your Setup every changes are there or not. (Or if you may have a syntax error)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To make it work as expected I would do the following:

1) Copy the three folders from ext/news/Resources/Private/Templates, Partials, Layouts to fileadmin/templates/example/news
(I believe you have already done that)

2) Then place this in to your template provider or page **typoscript constants**:

```
plugin.tx_news {
    view {
        templateRootPath = fileadmin/templates/example/news/Templates/
        partialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/example/news/Partials/
        layoutRootPath = fileadmin/templates/example/news/Layouts/
    }
}
```

Now the news extension will use the Template files placed in fileadmin/

Next step would be to add some pageTSConfig inside your root pages properties in case you need more flexibility. For example like this:

```
tx_news.templateLayouts {
    1 = Special List Item
    2 = Special Detail Layout
}
```

That allows you to select one of these template layouts in your news plugin and to use conditions in your template file:

```
<f:if condition="{settings.templateLayout} == 1">
    <f:then>
        <!-- markup for a special list item -->
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <!-- markup for another list item -->
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Comment: You should not use the deprecated `templateRootPath` etc. anymore, but use the plural version, `templateRootPaths`.

Comment: If you mean that [forge entry](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/66306), I did not know about that. However it works in my case for 6.2.25 as well as 7.6.9 installations.

Comment: Actually in constants you can use the singular because it is a constant and in setup you should use the plural because this is the logic to handle multiple templates with fallback.